# Routing issues with codeigniter on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am attempting to produce my website on the web server, but am having some confusing codeigniter routing issues.  I took out the index.php by using the following .htacess in my root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have tried pretty much everything that I have found throughout stackoverflow and other sources, including moving around the / and changing the uri protocol. Nothing from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401911/codeigniter-isnt-routing-right) (among others), have worked for me. I believe that I am removing the index.php in the right way, but I still get the following 404 error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
```

Below is my some information from my **config.php** file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Any additional info or reasons why this would occur would be extremely helpful.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] - try with this (question mark after index.php) - some servers need it.

Comment: no luck on that.  It makes the page go into a redirect loop on the localhost as well.  thank you though