# Codeigniter doesn't find assets(css|js|images)

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, routes, virtualhost

I have the following virtual host config in windows:

```
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\example"
    ServerName example.com
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\example">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the I have the assets folder inside `example` folder in `htdocs(xampp)`.
The problem is when I open `example.com/home` it views the page without assets(throws `404 Error`).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. Basically, codeigniter controls all paths. You need to set up an .htaccess file which allows certain paths to avoid codeigniter such as the css, javascript, images, etc.

Something like this should help:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|style|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

(You may or may not need to change the last line; "index.php/$1" might need to be "/index.php/$1" depending on your server setup.)

Comment: I have a .htaccess which omits the index.php file.\

Comment: More of the same on this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401911/codeigniter-isnt-routing-right?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of a configuration that I use for Apache 2.4 - may require some syntax changes to work for 2.2, however the Rewrite rules should be fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# codeigniter urls
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# application routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The "application routing" piece tells Apache to route the request to PHP only if the paths do not exist as files or directories.